# The linked program is no longer installed Toast message on click of android market app on HTC-Evo(Sprint)

Tags: android

[image]The linked program is no longer installed Toast message on click of android market app

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall your android market application.

Comment: The android market app does not appear in my "Manage Applications List"...:(

Comment: I deleted the short cut from home screen. then reboot the device but no luck then i did factory reset. It Worked with factory reset.Now my android market is up.